# inserting rows in 2 tables dependent on insert id of each other

Tags: mysql

Working with existing tables in a ticketing application, so I can't change the structure.  I'm trying to insert a new row into the user_table, which requires an id from the email_table.  However, the email table requires a user id.  Why designed with this type of cross reference I have no idea and it seems like a terrible idea. But what's the best way to go about inserting rows into these?  Insert into the user_table and use a place holder value for the email_id, then insert into the email table get the real insert value then update the user_table?

The "id" in both tables is an auto_increment integer (primary keys), and the other fields cannot be null.

```
user_table
-------------
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `org_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `default_email_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `org_id` (`org_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 



email_table
---------------
CREATE TABLE `user_email` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `flags` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `address` (`address`),
  KEY `user_email_lookup` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| org_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| default_email_id | int(10)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| status           | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| name             | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created          | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated          | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| flags   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| address | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please can you show the actual schema for these 2 tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` and copy/paste the output to your question

Comment: Are you doing this in raw SQL or are you using a programming language over the top, like PHP

Comment: I'll be using php, gimme a minute and i'll print the schema

Comment: If fixing the schema is really not on, then I would suggest you do as you suggested, but run the 2 inserts and the update inside a transaction, so you get both records created and the id plugged in all done, or all rolledback. :)